# How to implement Joystick code using in C++ using Microsoft's IDirectInputDevice8?

Tags: c++, directshow, directx-9, joystick, directinput

I need to do blocking and non **blocking** **calls** to poll on an Direct Input device using **IDirectInputDevice8** interface.

In linux to do blocking, we use **select** ex:

```
while( ::select(_jdev+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0) 
{
    if( ::read( _jdev, &js, sizeof( js_event ) ) != sizeof( js_event ) )
    {
        perror( "Joystick : read error" );
        return;
    }

    _handleEvent( js );
}
```

How can I do the same thing using the **idirectinputdevice8** **interface**:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417816(v=vs.85).aspx

Even if I set  **IDirectInputDevice8::SetEventNotification()**, I still have to call poll() everytime to fetch new data and this is not workable solution since it will cause the cpu to spin.

How can I accomplish this?

*** At the moment, I can find,iterate,connect and fetch data from the Joystick Device. I just do not have blocking calls implemented.

...HERE is my experimental/test code... Please Ignore Syntax errors

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dinput.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "joystick.h"


LPDIRECTINPUT8 di;
HRESULT hr;
LPDIRECTINPUTDEVICE8 joystick;
DIDEVCAPS capabilities;

BOOL CALLBACK
enumCallback(const DIDEVICEINSTANCE* instance, VOID* context)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = di->CreateDevice(instance->guidInstance, &joystick, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return DIENUM_CONTINUE;
    }
    return DIENUM_STOP;
}

int JoyStickProp()
{
    if (FAILED(hr = joystick->SetDataFormat(&c_dfDIJoystick2))) {
        return hr;
    }
    if (FAILED(hr = joystick->SetCooperativeLevel(NULL, DISCL_EXCLUSIVE |
        DISCL_FOREGROUND))) {
        return hr;
    }
    capabilities.dwSize = sizeof(DIDEVCAPS);
    if (FAILED(hr = joystick->GetCapabilities(&capabilities))) {
        return hr;
    }
}

HRESULT JoyStickPoll(DIJOYSTATE2 *js)
{
    HRESULT     hr;

    if (joystick == NULL) {
        return S_OK;
    }

    // Poll the device to read the current state
    hr = joystick->Poll();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        hr = joystick->Acquire();
        while (hr == DIERR_INPUTLOST) {
            hr = joystick->Acquire();
        }

        if ((hr == DIERR_INVALIDPARAM) || (hr == DIERR_NOTINITIALIZED)) {
            return E_FAIL;
        }

        // If another application has control of this device, return successfully.
        // We'll just have to wait our turn to use the joystick.
        if (hr == DIERR_OTHERAPPHASPRIO) {
            return S_OK;
        }
    }

    // Get the input's device state
    if (FAILED(hr = joystick->GetDeviceState(sizeof(DIJOYSTATE2), js))) {
        return hr; // The device should have been acquired during the Poll()
    }

    return S_OK;
}

int main()
{


    // Create a DirectInput device
    if (FAILED(hr = DirectInput8Create(GetModuleHandle(NULL), DIRECTINPUT_VERSION,
        IID_IDirectInput8, (VOID**)&di, NULL))) {
        return hr;
    }

    // Look for the first simple joystick we can find.
    if (FAILED(hr = di->EnumDevices(DI8DEVCLASS_GAMECTRL, enumCallback,
        NULL, DIEDFL_ATTACHEDONLY))) {
        return hr;
    }
    // Make sure we got a joystick
    if (joystick == NULL) {
        printf("Joystick not found.\n");
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    JoyStickProp();
    DIJOYSTATE2 diState;

    HANDLE ghWriteEvent;
    // Create joystick event stuff here
    ghWriteEvent = CreateEvent(
        NULL,               // default security attributes
        FALSE,               // manual-reset event
        FALSE,              // initial state is nonsignaled
        TEXT("WriteEvent")  // object name
        );

    //makesure we can read fromt the joystick before waiting for an event
    JoyStickPoll(&diState);
    printf("x axis %d", diState.lX);
    printf("y axis %d", diState.lY);
    JoyStickPoll(&diState);
    printf("x axis %d", diState.lX);
    printf("y axis %d", diState.lY);
    JoyStickPoll(&diState);
    printf("x axis %d", diState.lX);
    printf("y axis %d", diState.lY);
    JoyStickPoll(&diState);
    printf("x axis %d", diState.lX);
    printf("y axis %d", diState.lY);
    JoyStickPoll(&diState);
    printf("x axis %d", diState.lX);
    printf("y axis %d", diState.lY);
    JoyStickPoll(&diState);
    printf("x axis %d", diState.lX);
    printf("y axis %d", diState.lY);
joystick->SetEventNotification(ghWriteEvent);
    while (TRUE) {

        DWORD dwResult = WaitForSingleObject(
            ghWriteEvent, // event handle
            INFINITE);

        switch (dwResult) {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            // Event 1 has been set. If the event was created as
            // autoreset, it has also been reset. 
            int x = 0;
            //ProcessInputEvent1();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Watch those underscores.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) Be really annoying if there is a `_handleEvent` or `_jdev` defined in your compiler's Standard Library implementation that is getting crossed with your code.

Comment: That's  Linux code as an example for what I want o accomplish in windows... it does not have anything to do with windows code or the current issue.

Comment: Irrelevant. Underscores have special meaning in C++ laid out by the C++ Standard. The rules are the same regardless of whether the code is for Linux or Windows. Only the results will differ. Be careful how you use them.

Comment: You handle notification event and poll only if there is a state change. You don't need to poll and _spin CPU_ unless state changes.

Comment: @Roman Yes! but How do I do that?? 

Notification events do not get generated until I call directInputdevice8::poll:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectinputdevice8.idirectinputdevice8.poll(v=vs.85).aspx

I added notification events to my code and can see the event does not get triggered until I call poll.

Comment: No, you are to poll as a result of receiving the notification, which in turn is generated by the API.

Comment: IT WORKS NOW!!!! and THIS is an example of how to do  joysticks in using Directinput ..THANKS REMY and ROMAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for [`IDirectInputDevice8::SetEventNotification()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectinputdevice8.idirectinputdevice8.seteventnotification.aspx) gives you relevant code snippets.

You need to call [`CreateEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396.aspx) and provide the returned `HANDLE` as an argument to `SetEventNotification()`. The event will be signaled for you when a state change occurs.  You can wait on the event, and then once you have the notification, you get new state data using [`IDirectInputDevice8::GetDeviceState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectinputdevice8.idirectinputdevice8.getdevicedata.aspx).

All standard [Wait Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms687069) are applicable to waiting for the event to be signaled. The following code snippet shows you one way, using [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242.aspx):

```
while (TRUE) { 

    dwResult = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(2, ah, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT); 
    switch (dwResult) { 
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0: 
            // Event 1 has been set. If the event was created as
            // autoreset, it has also been reset. 
            ProcessInputEvent1();
            break;
```

The [`IDirectInputDevice8::Poll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectinputdevice8.idirectinputdevice8.poll.aspx) method is used for devices that do not generate event notifications.  You are supposed to poll them because they are not capable of operating the way you want them to.

> Some joysticks and other game devices, or particular objects on them, [do not generate hardware interrupts and do not return any data or signal any events until you call the `IDirectInputDevice8::Poll` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418748).

You poll only when you need to when notifications don't work for a device. The link above explains how to identify whether polling is necessary.

Comment: I have done that and unless I did it incorrectly, the event does not get called until I call poll. What I want to do /and what should happen is wait for a state change event then I can call poll.

Comment: I just realized I created an event and a separate thread for it to run on  .. so maybe that is throwing things off.. let me try and get back to you

Comment: @lukesignh: Events created with `CreateEvent()` are not tied to any particular thread.  One or more threads can wait on an event while another thread signals it.  So that is not your problem.  Please [edit] your question to show the actual code that is not working for you.

Comment: @lukesignh did you read the [Polling and Event Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418748) documentation that Roman linked you to? "*To find out whether it is necessary to call `IDirectInputDevice8::Poll` each time you want to retrieve data, first set the data format for the device, then call the `IDirectInputDevice8::GetCapabilities` method and check for the `DIDC_POLLEDDATAFORMAT` flag in the `DIDEVCAPS` structure.*" Your code is not checking the output of `GetCapabilities()` to know whether to use `Poll()` or `SetEventNotification()`